# how to remove "" from the vector in R

Tags: r

How can I remove the "to be able to download the vector's content
i have vector:

```
>wspólne
   1    1   29    1    0   37    1   45                          
 "1"  "1" "29"  "1"  "0" "37"  "1" "45" "31" "12"  "2" "32" "25"
```

when he wants to get a value from this vector, he gets something like that

```
waga_linków[wspólne]
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

how to write it correctly to get all the values without "" ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
wspólne <- as.numeric(wspólne) # coerce character to be numeric
waga_linków[wspólne]
```